# Incorrect scrolling after vertical centering

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem, after setting position: `absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -310px` for my main content. The problem is when I minimalize the browser window and the vertical scroll appears, top part of the layout is hidden.

Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/95Uzt/15/. You can see the menu and contact form but the header above the form is not visible/covered by the browser. What is wrong?

Comment: This will happen when the height of the viewport is less than 620 pixels (so that -310px is placed above 50% of the height of the viewport). How you fix this depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I wanted the content to be more or less centered vertically in every browser (that's why I used top:50% and margin-top: -310px) but I also need it to scroll properly. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to handle two cases with one piece of code, and that's just not working. You're going to need to use some kind of conditional code to handle the two cases.

Your two cases are:

- For a viewport more than 620 pixels, you need to center the content
- For a viewport less than 620 pixels, you need the content top aligned.

For more modern browsers that support it, you could look into using CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 620px) {  
  .content
  {
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

If you need more extensive browser support, you'll need to use javascript, I think.